# How to get android outputs folder in Gradle build script (absolute path)

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtNXM.png)

How can I get the outputs folder's absolute path in Gradle script

using

- Gradle version 4.1
- compileSdkVersion 23
- buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `${project.buildDir}` or `${buildDir}` in your gradle script.